# Multiple level BOM calculation

Tags: erp, byte-order-mark

I have product with multiple level BOM structure (maximum is 12 level).
Could you let me know which solution to calculate it in the fastest way? (which technology, language, or algorithm?)

Comment: probably BOM can be modeled over a graph? In this case you can traverse it with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: I'm using recursive query within sql but performance very slowly. Do you know how to increase performance?

Comment: Sorry, is difficult to approach the problem with so few information. I can give only general tips:  be sure to index on proper fields, eventually use stored procedures. Do not disconnect/reconnect at every query.